# In Microsoft Word 2010, is it possible to automatically retrieve a list of page numbers for tracked changes?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, change-tracking

I have an upcoming project that will require a detailed list of document changes.  We can either use change bars in the document itself, or provide a detailed list of revisions, including each page number that has been changed.  I know I can open up the Reviewing Pane and select and copy that entire list. However, the list doesn't show the page number on which each change appears. Is there a setting in Track Changes that will display the page numbers for each change?  (I've Googled a bit as well as looking at the Track Changes Options window.) If it's not a setting, a macro solution also works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under File | Print, there's an option to print only the markup.  This includes the page numbers.

This Microsoft Office Support page describes the setting: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Print-a-document-showing-tracked-changes-and-comments-c563899d-d205-4de0-a0f5-64908a22347f#bm3

I used it on a sample document and got this output, which will work:

> Document3
>
> Main document changes and comments
>
> Page 19: Inserted Keck, Kelly L. 2/23/2015 11:23:00 AM
>
> Page 19: Moved to page 19 (Move #1) Keck, Kelly L. 2/23/2015 11:23:00 AM
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
>   nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
>   consequat.
>
> Page 19: Deleted Keck, Kelly L. 2/23/2015 11:23:00 AM
>
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
>   tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim
>   veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
>   ea commodo consequat
>
> Page 19: Inserted Keck, Kelly L. 2/23/2015 11:23:00 AM
>
> Page 19: Moved from page 19 (Move #1) Keck, Kelly L. 2/23/2015 11:23:00 AM
>
> Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
>   exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>
> Header and footer changes
>
> Text Box changes
>
> Header and footer text box changes
>
> Footnote changes
>
> Endnote changes